# Как занести текущее время в бд?

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Я начал знакомиться с шарпом и в задании мне нужно занести текущее время (вплоть до секунд) в бд. Попробовал несколько вариантов, но не один из них мне не помог, поэтому я снова здесь.

```
        private protected bool Checking(string login, string pass)
    {
        try
        {
            var database = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(@"server=123;
                                                user=123;
                                                database=123;
                                                port=123;
                                                password=123;");


            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(); //создание переменной для удобства
            con.ConnectionString = database.ConnectionString; //подключение к бд
            con.Open(); //открытие бд
            MySqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand(); //команда для бд
            cmnd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM LoginedChuvaku WHERE Login = '{login}'";
            var a = cmnd.ExecuteReader(); //чтение из бд

            while (a.Read())
            {
                if (HWIDserver == HWIDlocal)
                {

                }
                else
                {
DateTime bantime = DateTime.Now;
                        MySqlCommand InsertToLoginedChuvaku = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO LoginedChuvaku" +
                            "(bantime)" +
                            " VALUES " +
                            $"('{bantime}')", con);
                        //InsertToLoginedChuvaku.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", somename);
                        InsertToLoginedChuvaku.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", bantime);
                        a.Close();
                        InsertToLoginedChuvaku.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

А также ещё одна проблема. Я не могу вывести текст из бд. Он выдаёт мне ту строчку, что и написана, не берёт данные из неё. Я, возможно, догадываюсь почему. Т.к. это просто string и он запоминает её. Мне нужно как-то задействовать этот string, чтобы он получил значение из бд, но как - не знаю.

```
       private protected bool Checking(string login, string pass)
    {
        try
        {
            var database = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(@"server=123;
                                                user=123;
                                                database=123;
                                                port=123;
                                                password=123;");


            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(); //создание переменной для удобства
            con.ConnectionString = database.ConnectionString; //подключение к бд
            con.Open(); //открытие бд
            MySqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand(); //команда для бд
            cmnd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM LoginedChuvaku WHERE Login = '{login}'";
         //та самая строчка   string reason = $"SELECT reason FROM LoginedChuvaku WHERE Login = '{login}'";
//исправил так - string reason = a.GetString("reason"); //только нужно перенести в цикл.
            string reasonshow = $"Resources: {reason}";
            var a = cmnd.ExecuteReader(); //чтение из бд
            while (a.Read())
            {
                if (HWIDserver == HWIDlocal)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime restime = DateTime.Now;
                    string setreason = "Test";
                    string reasonstr = $"UPDATE `LoginedChuvaku` SET `reason` = '{setreason}' WHERE `LoginedChuvaku`.`UID` = {a.GetString("UID")}";
                    MySqlCommand reasoncmd = new MySqlCommand(reasonstr, con);
                    a.Close();
                    reasoncmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Используйте _параметризованный_ запрос. Точка.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, вторую проблему решил, а первая с датой для меня остаётся загадкой. Я почитал о параметризованных запросах, но не понимаю как её реализовать в моём коде.

Comment: Вы опять незнамо зачем делаете два запроса: select и update. Хотя достаточно одного update с where. Я бы предложил вам заняться именно sql. Попишите запросы, поосваивайте возможности СУБД. Практически во всех БД есть функции получения даты-времени. Нет нужды делать получать его в C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand InsertToLoginedChuvaku = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ...", sqlConnection);
InsertToClients.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", somename);
InsertToClients.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", restime);
InsertToClients.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: для чего нужен второй параметр я понял, но зачем нужен первый ?

Comment: код обновил. Ошибку выдает `Field "Password" doesn't have a default value.` Если же в бд указать значение по умолчанию для этого столбика, то оно говорит на следующее.

Comment: @eco это просто пример как передать несколько параметров. У вас в таблице есть столбцы, которые не null и у которых нет значения по умолчанию - их нужно либо тоже передавать в параметрах новой записи, либо менять структуру таблицы.